# R Multiple Lines on a Chart

Tags: r, charts, line

I am trying to place 3 columns onto a line chart.
But while I can create the chart the lines are not being drawn correctly.

Below are some data and the two different ways I've tried to create the charts.

any help is great;y appreciated.

Data:

```
structure(list(Year = c("2017-08", "2017-09", "2017-10", "2017-11", 
"2017-12", "2018-01", "2018-02", "2018-03", "2018-04", "2018-05", 
"2018-06", "2018-07", "2018-08", "2018-09", "2018-10", "2018-11", 
"2018-12", "2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-03", "2019-04", "2019-05", 
"2019-06", "2019-07", "2019-08", "2019-09", "2019-10", "2019-11", 
"2019-12", "2020-01", "2020-02", "2020-03", "2020-04", "2020-05", 
"2020-06", "2020-07", "2020-08"), Order.Comment.1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "BR", "BST", "CG", "CN", "CT", 
"DM", "DR", "EM", "EMR", "EMURG", "ENDOC", "EYE", "FF", "GI", 
"GYN", "GYNAE", "HAEM", "HN", "ICC", "LBX", "LYMPH", "MN", "MOHS", 
"NEUR", "NEURO", "NO REPORT ISSUED", "PAED", "PAEDGI", "PERI", 
"PG", "RE", "SK", "TEST PATIENT", "UGI", "UR", "URGI"), class = "factor"), 
    P.Less.3 = c(50.8250825082508, 53.7906137184115, 54.8172757475083, 
    47.6190476190476, 51.8939393939394, 56.508875739645, 52.2900763358779, 
    49.3421052631579, 43.3447098976109, 50.4918032786885, 50.1501501501502, 
    49.7206703910614, 47.5409836065574, 46.0264900662252, 45.6896551724138, 
    47.2312703583062, 44.3965517241379, 57.8313253012048, 49.8098859315589, 
    48.6013986013986, 49.0566037735849, 45.3531598513011, 49.063670411985, 
    53.8961038961039, 50, 43.5810810810811, 45, 47.3509933774834, 
    43.4782608695652, 39.041095890411, 36.9649805447471, 43.2515337423313, 
    39.5522388059701, 54.6875, 46.2765957446808, 36.1990950226244, 
    40.7216494845361), P.Less.7 = c(87.7887788778878, 89.1696750902527, 
    89.0365448504983, 88.8888888888889, 87.8787878787879, 92.603550295858, 
    89.6946564885496, 87.8289473684211, 84.641638225256, 83.6065573770492, 
    83.1831831831832, 87.1508379888268, 89.0710382513661, 79.8013245033112, 
    79.3103448275862, 83.3876221498371, 81.0344827586207, 87.9518072289157, 
    82.8897338403042, 87.0629370629371, 81.8867924528302, 86.2453531598513, 
    82.7715355805243, 88.961038961039, 87.1428571428571, 83.7837837837838, 
    83.8888888888889, 84.1059602649007, 78.9855072463768, 84.5890410958904, 
    84.4357976653696, 84.6625766871166, 84.3283582089552, 91.40625, 
    79.7872340425532, 76.9230769230769, 72.680412371134), P.Less.10 = c(97.3597359735974, 
    97.4729241877256, 99.3355481727575, 98.4126984126984, 96.2121212121212, 
    98.5207100591716, 97.3282442748092, 97.3684210526316, 96.5870307167236, 
    94.0983606557377, 96.0960960960961, 96.3687150837989, 96.9945355191257, 
    92.3841059602649, 92.2413793103448, 95.4397394136808, 93.5344827586207, 
    95.1807228915663, 95.0570342205323, 97.9020979020979, 94.7169811320755, 
    95.1672862453532, 94.0074906367041, 95.7792207792208, 96.4285714285714, 
    95.6081081081081, 94.7222222222222, 95.364238410596, 93.8405797101449, 
    95.8904109589041, 95.7198443579767, 96.9325153374233, 94.7761194029851, 
    96.875, 95.2127659574468, 92.3076923076923, 85.0515463917526
    )), row.names = c(NA, 37L), class = "data.frame")
```

Way 1:

```
ggplot(Mth_TaT_Data, aes(x=Year, group = "BR")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = P.Less.3), color = "darkred") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = P.Less.7), color="steelblue", linetype="twodash")+ 
  geom_line(aes(y = P.Less.10), color="sienna1", linetype="dashed")+
  ggtitle("Test")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust = 1))
```

Way 2:

```
df <- Mth_TaT_Data %>%
  select(Year, Order.Comment.1,P.Less.3, P.Less.7, P.Less.10) %>%
  gather(key = "variable", value = "value", -Year, -Order.Comment.1)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, y = value,group = "BR")) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = variable))+
ggtitle("Test")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi James! what's the problem with way 1?

Comment: Hi James, can you please clarify how your requested output is different than the output provided by ["Way 1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ2pm.png) above? Perhaps you could mock it up in Paint or Preview?

Comment: in way 2 write `group = variable` instead of `group = "BR"` and it will show a chart similar to way 1

Comment: @Edo 
I've added what Way 1 looks like when I run it from the master data (the dput is just a smaller version of the larger data I'm working with)

Comment: @IanCampbell I've included an example of what the chart looks like when I run the code with Way 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of problems generally has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format, like the question itself shows the OP is trying to do in **way 2**. See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.

In the code below I first create three vectors:

1. `lvls` is a vector of the column names that start with `"P"`, to be used as the levels of the long format column `variable` and as the names of the two other vectors that are created;
2. `linetp` is a named vector of line types;
3. `colr` is a named vector of (line) colors.

And the final code is therefore a bit longer than the question's.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

lvls <- grep("^P", names(Mth_TaT_Data), value = TRUE)
linetp <- setNames(c("solid", "twodash", "dashed"), lvls)
colr <- setNames(c("darkred", "steelblue", "sienna1"), lvls)


Mth_TaT_Data %>%
  mutate(Year = paste(Year, "01", sep = "-"),
         Year = zoo::as.yearmon(Year)) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with('P'),
    names_to = 'variable',
    values_to = 'value'
  ) %>%
  mutate(variable = factor(variable, levels = lvls)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype = variable, color = variable)) +
  ggtitle("Test") +
  scale_color_manual(values = colr) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = linetp) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: That doesn't work for me I get the below error message

''Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Year`.
x there is no package called ‘zoo’
i Input `Year` is `zoo::as.yearmon(Year)`.'

Comment: @JamesSlasor Try `as.Date` instead of `zoo::as.yearmon`. The latter outputs dates of year and month (no days), like in the test data set.

Comment: Massive help. It looked like I needed to filter my data down to what I had in my output above, and not try and shoehorn it into the whole actual data set.

Answer (score 1):

Following the comments of our valious colleages, it is bizarre what you want. If you want one line per column the strategy you followed in the first plot might be right. Maybe you want to see each line in a legend, so an approach reshaping data with `tidyverse` would work. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
Mth_TaT_Data %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(1,2)) %>%
  mutate(name=factor(name,levels=unique(name),ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Year, y=value,group = name,color=name,linetype=name)) + 
  geom_line()+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("darkred","steelblue","sienna1"))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid","twodash","dashed"))+
  ggtitle("Test")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust = 1))+
  labs(color='Column',linetype='Column')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I get the error message 'Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 15 needed but only 3 provided.' and I think its to do with the 'pivot_longer(-c(1,2))' as this is deleting the first and second of the 5 parts of the data extract.
If I do a data.frame containing these columns only and then run this would that be an idea.

Comment: @JamesSlasor Hi James, it is not removing the vars, that is keeping. You have 15 columns in your data so make this change, add 15 colors or try with a sample of columns to test initially what you get!.