# Wrong matching of colours in ggplot using scale color discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, scale-color-manual

```r
ggplot() + 
    geom_line(data=Final_UDR_summary, aes(y=pass_rate_IIR, x=year_week, color="blue"),size=1) + 
    geom_line(data=Final_UDR_summary, aes(y=pass_rate_IQR, x=year_week, color="red"),size=1) +
    geom_line(data=Final_UDR_summary, aes(y=pass_rate_DR, x=year_week, color="green"),size=1)  +
    scale_color_discrete(name="Pass rate name",labels=c("pass_rate_IIR", "pass_rate_IQR", "pass_rate_DR")) + 
    ggtitle("Plot of pass rate over time") + xlab("Time in interval of weeks") + ylab("Pass Rates")
```

This is producing a graph but the color of the line is off from the data and it definitely doesn't match the legend which is automatically generated.

[image]

Comment: Does your data contain missing value?

Comment: When you set constants, e.g., `color = "blue"`, rather than mapping column names, you need to put them **outside** `aes()`. Though a better approach overall would be long format data with a single `geom_line` call and color mapped to a column name.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64337329/8245406) help?