# ggplot is displaying variables from the same data frame out of order

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I have a data frame with two columns.
The main one is GDP, the other is the quarter.
I make the gdp graph is ok. However, when I add the moving average, it doesn't respect color or order.

```
graf <- data %>% ggplot(aes(x = TRIMESTRE)) +
geom_line(aes(y = PIB, colour = "black")) +
geom_line(aes(y = rollmean(PIB, 6, na.pad = TRUE), colour = "red"))
graf
```

[image: graf]

Link of file:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PHfkkaBRznQ8H1eMwLqg8ivFLjuw90BG?usp=share_link

It's a question because it's not right, because there are other ways to make the graph... it's more to know where I'm really going wrong.

I appreciate any help

I believe it should be with the colors as entered in the code...

Comment: Try `+ scale_color_manual(values = c(red = "red", black = "black"))` to set your desired colors.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a duplicate, but you need to put your colo(u)r specifications *outside of the `aes()` call, i.e.

```r
... +
geom_line(aes(y = PIB), colour = "black") +
geom_line(aes(y = rollmean(PIB, 6, na.pad = TRUE)), colour = "red")
```

(look carefully, the only thing that changed is the location of two close-parens)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67676849/wrong-matching-of-colours-in-ggplot-using-scale-color-discrete) raises the same issue (but is unanswered except in a comment).